# Binomial and Uniform joint distribution statistics question.

Tags: probability, statistics

I was just wondering if someone could explain the solution to this example in my textbook for me. I am not really understanding it. The question is, 
X follows Binomial(n,p) and p follows Uniform(0,1). Show, P(X =0) = P(X = 1) = · · · = P(X = n). You are given that the integral of the binomial distribution over (0,1) is equal to  [i!(n-1)!]/(n+1)!.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$P(X=k)=\binom{n}{k}\int_0^1 p^k(1-p)^{n-k}dp$.
Integrate by parts $du=(1-p)^{n-k}dp,\ v=p^k$.
You will get$P(X=k)=\binom{n}{k} \frac{k}{n-k+1}\int_0^1 p^{k-1}(1-p)^{n-k+1}dp=P(X=k-1)$

Therefore all P(X=k) are equal.

Answer (score -1):

You have a joint distribution of a discrete and continous random variable.

$$f_{X,U}(x,u)=\binom{n}{x}\cdot u^x\cdot (1-u)^{n-x} \ \ \forall \ x=\{1,2,\ldots, n \}$$

To get $f_X(x)$ you integrate the joint distribution.

$$f_X(x)=P(X=k)=\int_0^1 \binom{n}{x}\cdot u^x\cdot (1-u)^{n-x}\, du=\binom{n}{x}\cdot\int_0^1  u^x\cdot (1-u)^{n-x}\, du$$

Then use the hint: $\int_0^1  u^x\cdot (1-u)^{n-x}\, du= \frac{x!(n-\color{red}x)!}{(n+1)!}$